# Write a row of a matrix in a file

Tags: r, file

I have a simple matrix with n rows and m columns:

```
param <- mat.or.vec(n,m)
```

(`n` and `m` are variables  defined earlier.)

I then populate the matrix with random numbers so the matrix is not empty.

I would like to write each row in a different file, with each entry separated by a tab. So for example for the first row I use:

```
write.table(param[1,],"param1.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

However, when I try this, I get a file where the row is in column form.
That is, instead of the desired result:

```
a b c d
```

I get

```
a
b
c
d
```

I really don't understand why I get such a thing... Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
write.table(param[1,,drop=FALSE],"param1.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Now I feel really stupid because the answer is very simple! But at least I've learned the existence of `drop=FALSE`. Thanks!